# How to load / insert initial data into database with Ebean in Play Framework?

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I need to some initial data (from csv files) into database. I am using Ebean with Play! Framework. I read the [doc](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaGuide2). It says using YAML files to store the data and call Ebean.save(). And this is done in a Test.

My questions:

1. Where should I insert my data? (Test is probably not the ideal place, as this data should be used in production)
2. Can I write my own code to get my data from existing csv files, instead of using YAML files?

Any suggestions or doc links will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With further search, I found the solution is described [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaGuide3)

The code that perform initial insertion needs to be hooked into Play's startup.

> Hooking into Play’s startup is as simple as creating a class called Global that implements GlobalSettings in the root package, and overriding the onStart() method. Let’s do that now, by creating the app/Global.java fileHooking into Play’s startup is as simple as creating a class called Global that implements GlobalSettings in the root package, and overriding the onStart() method. Let’s do that now, by creating the app/Global.java file

Note that, it said the class needs to be in the root package.

code example:

```
import play.*;
import play.libs.*;
import com.avaje.ebean.Ebean;
import models.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
    @Override
    public void onStart(Application app) {
        // Check if the database is empty
        if (User.find.findRowCount() == 0) {
            Ebean.save((List) Yaml.load("initial-data.yml")); // You can use whatever data source you have here. No need to be in YAML.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this was deprecated

Answer (score 7):

A Play Framework 2.4 solution to loading initial data on application startup, using Ebean:

First, create a class where you want perform the initial data load.  According to the docs this [has to be in the constructor.](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/GlobalSettings#Java)

```
public class InitialData {
    public InitialData() {

        if (Ebean.find(User.class).findRowCount() == 0) {
            InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("initial-data.yml");

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Map<String, List<Object>> all = 
                (Map<String, List<Object>>)Yaml.load(is, this.getClass().getClassLoader());

            //Yaml.load("initial-data.yml"); //calls Play.application() which isn't available yet
            Ebean.save(all.get("users"));
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: I used Yaml's `load(InputStream is, ClassLoader classloader)` method over its `load(String resourceName)` method because it does not work.  I believe this is because of its use of Play.application(), as this is not available before the application is started. [Source Here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/M4kWMtrEdg8/MIzfq2h4WvYJ)

Second, According to Play docs, to execute code before startup, use [Eager-bindings.](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaDependencyInjection#Eager-bindings) This will cause your code in the InitialData constructor to execute.

```
public class MainModule extends AbstractModule implements AkkaGuiceSupport {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        //this is where the magic happens
        bind(InitialData.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }
}
```

Make sure to add your MainModule class to the application.conf

```
# modules
play.modules.enabled += "module.MainModule"
```